# Why is web content wrapped in a wrapper div?

Tags: html, css, structure

I have three elements in a webpage. They are all the same width:

```
h1, ul, p {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

They look like this:

```
                        +----------------------------------+
                        |             Heading              |
                        |                                  |
                        +----------------------------------+
                        +----------------------------------+
                        | Home | About | Whatever | Else   |
                        +----------------------------------+
                        +----------------------------------+
                        | Bla bla bla? Bla bla bla, bla    |
                        | bla bla. Bla bla bla: "Bla bla." |
                        +----------------------------------+
```

Why would I need to wrap them all in a wrapper-div?

```
<div id="wrapper">  ⬅︎ What for?
    <h1></h1>
    <ul></ul>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Billions of webpages do this, yet I don't understand why this is necessary.

Comment: Generally because the `body` is supposed to be 100% width and 100% height (i.e. covering the whole browser window), and it just makes it cleaner to apply the width to the wrapper instead of the `body`.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 That's interesting. I never thought about it from this perspective. Is there some specification that says that the body should be 100%?

Comment: Uhh, not sure if there's a specification as far as I'm aware; it's just a general convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already guessed, a wrapper `div` generally *isn't* necessary.  So why is it so often used?  Simple answer:  Internet Explorer.

Some CSS styles were not supported on the `body` element in early versions of Internet Explorer.  Using a wrapper `div` was a popular solution for dealing with this.

Even though this is no longer a problem, old habits die hard, and many developers still use the technique when creating new pages.  And when old pages get updated, there's little incentive to remove existing wrapper `div`s from them.

Over time, I imagine you'll see this technique used less and less often.

For more in-depth discussion, see 
**http://tjvantoll.com/2013/01/05/is-it-safe-to-use-the-body-as-a-top-level-container-yet/**

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your css to the wrapper div as

```
#wrapper {
   width: 900px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

No need to apply above CSS to each and every element.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply that CSS rule to your wrapper, so you won't need to apply it for everything individually.

We use the wrappers to "contain" something and set it's width,height and other positions only once.
So we don't need to write CSS rules for every other possible elements in that wrapper or on the website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "need" for a wraper div other then that it could possibly be increased code readabillity and it could possibly make it more easy to do things with javascript or css that would apply to all divs. 
Most of these benefits could be achived with proper class names aswell!

Answer (score 0):

Why wrappers are used often?

- You have to set the width only once.
- Easy to center on the page.
- Makes adding a sidebar easier.
- Responsive design / template.